# how do i make a flash element mobile friendly with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, browser, swfobject

if I have a site that has a flash header, but it's not mobile friendly on apple products and even some androids, what is the javascript code I can insert into my .html page so that it doesn't show this when it is loaded...

What I'm trying to fix:

[image]

Comment: You can hide the flash header on mobile. Here are some ways to do it: https://ajarproductions.com/blog/2013/10/17/easily-hide-elements-from-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HTML5's `innerHTML` option with JavaScript to check whether Flash is available or not. From that info, you could then show alternative content like some image file if the device cannot display an `.swf` file (Flash app).

Since you did not show any code of your own page header setup, I'll show a basic example and maybe you can apply logic to your own page.

- Put code in blank document (edit widths/heights) and save as `.html`.
- In your browser **block** Flash and refresh... it shows image banner.
- In your browser **enable* Flash and refresh... it shows Flash banner.

Test this code and ask any questions for clarification:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body> 

<div id="my_Banner"></div>

</body>


<script>

var show_A = '<embed width=600 height=200 src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf">';

var show_B = '<img width=600 height=200 src="https://www.videocopilot.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/trap.jpg"/>';

function isFlashEnabled() 
{
    var flash = navigator.plugins.namedItem('Shockwave Flash');
    if (!flash) { return 0; } 
    else { return 1; }
}


if( isFlashEnabled() ) //if Flash is availabe as browser plugin
{ document.getElementById('my_Banner').innerHTML = show_A; } 

else //if Flash not availabe as browser plugin (eg: on mobile browsers)
{ document.getElementById('my_Banner').innerHTML = show_B; }

</script>

</html>
```